# SQL - Order By Function for a1,a2,a3,a4...a101

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and running into difficulty.

If I have a column A1,A2,A3...A1000

When I order by this column, it appears A1,A100,A2... I get the logic why.

ATTEMPT: `order by left(length(company.company_code),-1) ASC;`

I attempted the above to try cut away the A but no luck?

Any advice?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Perhaps you can use a numeric sensitive collation.

Comment: What database system (please [edit] and add a suitable tag)

Comment: Any negative numbers? Always an A, and nothing more?

Comment: did you need a general solution for natural sort ? or just for this exemple ?

Comment: Well, I guess you notice already: When there is data in a column and you are interested in a part of it, this indicates that you should probably have separate columns instead (one for the letter, one for the number in your case).

Comment: Yes, thank you all. I am using MySql. @Gordons solution below worked very well and was logical!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple method:

```
order by length(company.company_code), company.company_code
```

This orders first by the length of the string and then the rest of the string.

You could also do something like this:

```
order by cast(substr(company.company_code, 2, 10) as int)
```

This assumes that there are no more than 9 digits after exactly one letter.

Comment: Ah great! So it's ordering by length i.e. A1 = 2 while A100 =3 and then by the company_code. Simple but genius!

Answer (score 0):

hi if first char is letter,

order by
substr(company.company_code,1,1), cast(substr(company.company_code,2,2) as int)

or
this code run in oracle

order by  regexp_replace('ARE12352','\d'), regexp_replace('ARE12352','\D')

Comment: adds nothing to a 7 year old accepted answer